# CodeSmith Insight vs FogBugz BugScout

Tags: wpf, error-handling

Both Codesmith and FogBugz have tools for automated error reporting. FogBugz has [BugzScout](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/docs/70/topics/customers/BugzScout.html) and Codesmith has [Insight](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/insight)

I am looking for feedback from people who have tried both of these tools so I can learn the pluses and minuses of each. I want to do automatic error reporting from WPF applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the FogBugz thing and it's pretty primitive. You just make some XML yourself (they have some C# example code that you can hack (I had to convert it to Java), and this code files a bug report. They do have some means of checking for duplicates so that's nice, but there is little more to it. It's just a little add on to FogBugz.

I love Fogbugz as a bug tracking system, but as a case management system (which this is related to) there are other better systems out there, and Fog Creek does not seem to be interested in improving these capabilities (we actually use Zendesk for the case handling, and have automatic submission to that for support requests).

I have not used Insight, but in looking at their comparison it appears that they are making this a big part of their product and have a lot more features; this is a real product by itself, so I would certainly take it very seriously.

Comment: I too use FogBugz. Lets hope they decide to make automated error capture as easy as Insight.

Answer (score 0):

In the same category of services that help you to track .NET exceptions would be [ExceptionTail](https://www.exceptiontail.com).
Take a look at the following answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562756